# XML/XSLT trasnsformed data export to excel in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a JSP in which I want to:

1. make an HTTP request;
2. get back the XML response;
3. transform the response using XSL; and
4. export the transformed data to excel.

But i do not get the entire data in a single HTTP call. Also I have to use two stylesheets for exporting to Excel. The first is for the first page of records, and the other is for all the other pages.

How can one do this in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), its a powerful API to read and create MS Office documents in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Could you parse the XML into Java objects, then when you have the complete object list simply write the Excel file using [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)? I've used this for Excel files and it's very simple & useful.